# how to not remove the (- , +) sign if it's in the beginning of the string in node js get query

Tags: node.js, backend

how to not remove the (-, +) sign if it's in the beginning of the string in node js get query

```
const time_zone = req.query.time_zone
```

result: " 02:00"

supposed to be: "+02:00"

Comment: Just `replace()` it back in.

Comment: it sometime be -  and sometime be + so I can't replace

Comment: Hint: Regular expression. Also if it's only ever going to be a space, `' ', '+'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` character is used to escape spaces in the query part of the URL. That's why

```js
new URL("http://server/?time_zone=+02:00").searchParams.get("time_zone")
```

gives `' 02:00'` (note the leading space). And `req.query.time_zone` is determined in this way. The `-` character has no such special treatment.

Strictly speaking, the client should call the URL `http://server/?time_zone=%2b02:00`, which gives `req.query.time_zone = '+02:00'`, but I suggest to take this burden away from the client by defining

```js
var time_zone = req.query.time_zone.replace(" ", "+");
```

which works with both variants.

Comment: Thanks this what I already made, but I appreciate your time